# Associativity? Can this be applied here?

Tags: propositional-calculus, associativity

As the Associativity law says that **(A ∧ B) ∧ C ≡ (A ∧ C) ∧ B**, can I do something like this?

**(A ∧ ¬B) ∨ (B ∧ ¬A) ≡ (A ∧ ¬A) ∨ (B ∧ ¬B)**

I am new with logic and I still don't get this basic principles..

Comment: that is not associativity. It results from associativity and commutativity.

Answer (score 0):

Associativity is a property that applies when you have several
operators all the same. So
$$
(A \wedge \lnot B) \wedge (B \wedge \lnot A) 
\equiv (A \wedge \lnot A) \wedge (B \wedge \lnot B).
$$
We can apply associativity there because every operator is $\wedge$.
(We also have to apply commutativity to get this result.)
But $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are different operators, so they don't associate:
$$
(A \wedge \lnot B) \vee (B \wedge \lnot A)
 \not\equiv (A \wedge \lnot A) \vee (B \wedge \lnot B). \tag1
$$
We can see the two sides are not necessarily the same
because there is a model
that satisfies $A\wedge\lnot B$, therefore it satisfies the left-hand
side of $(1)$, but the right-hand side of $(1)$ cannot be satisfied.

Comment: You might want to exclude the case $A\Leftrightarrow B$.

Comment: @user218931 Good point; I observed a model in which the two sides are different, but there are other models in which they're both false. What I really meant to say was that the proposed formula is not an identity.